# PHP round function returned a weird result

Tags: php, rounding

I just execute a simple script `round(8.32, 1)` in CGI, then it returns 8.300000000000001. But when I execute it in CLI with `php -r "echo round(8.32, 1);"`, the result is 8.3 which I expected. My PHP  version is 5.6.2.

Comment: Use `number_format()`, which returns a string.

Comment: How you output result for CGI version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have different settings of [precision](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.precision) in your config.

```
ini_set('precision', 10); var_dump(round(8.32, 1)); // double(8.3)

ini_set('precision', 20); var_dump(round(8.32, 1)); // double(8.3000000000000007105)
```

Why it happens you could read here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point

Answer (score 0):

`round()` returns a `float`, which is an approximation, and depending on how you display it may show roundoff error.

You should use `number_format()`, which returns a string.

```
echo number_format(8.32, 1);
```